# utility and operation of the function "EVP_PKEY_meth_find"

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

here is the function:

```
EVP_PKEY_meth_find (int type);
```

I would like to know what the "type" parameter corresponds to.
I did not see an explanation in the openssl documentation.

ps : I would also like to know what purpose this function can actually serve ?

Comment: Have you checked the docs here (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_meth_find.html)? Specifically: "*`EVP_PKEY_meth_find()` finds an **EVP_PKEY_METHOD** object with the **id**. This function first searches through the user-defined method objects and then the built-in objects.*"

Comment: yes, I imagine that the "id" is equal to "type" but precisely, how to find this value?

Comment: So you know what the `type` parameter "corresponds to" and you also "know what purpose this function can actually serve" if you've read the description. It's not clear to me what you're still missing. What are you trying to do? You should be creating new methods with `EVP_PKEY_meth_new(int id, int flags)`, which takes an `id` and then you can find them with `find`, no?